# Non-parametric test with two independent variables

Tags: nonparametric

My dependent variable is a raw score at some test that has a likert scale (ordinal data). My two independent variables are sex (male or female) and amyloid status (AB+ or AB-). I want to test the main effects of both IVs on the DV and also their interaction. The distribution of the dependent variable is not normal so I want to use a non-parametric test. I think I would need a non-parametric equivalent to a two-way ANOVA. Which test would suit my research question?